# Algorithm to split a rectangle around multiple points

Tags: algorithm, split, rectangles

I'm creating a building generator for a video game. The buildings are made of multiple levels.

Each level is subdivided into rooms using a binary space partitioning. At each iteration (up to a max number of iterations, defined by the game designer), all rooms are split either vertically or horizontally at a random location, making sure the 2 created rooms have both their width and height greater than a given value.

When all the rooms of the level are created, I insert one staircase to allow the player to go to the next floor.

Then I create the rooms on the next floor. I start by manually creating a room around the opening of the staircase of the level below is, to make sure the BSP algorithm won't place walls there. Depending on its location, I can create 2 rooms (if the staircase is in a corner for example), up to 4 rooms (if the staircase is in the center of the floor). Finally, I re-apply the BSP algorithm in those rooms.

Now, I'd like to be able to handle the splitting of the N+1 floor in case I have multiple staircase openings. The only requirement is that I can not have walls traversing those openings.

I could, of course, use a brute-force approach, but maybe there is something faster than that.

Here is a visual example of what I would like the algorithm to do:

On the left is the first floor of the building created by my existing BSP algorithm. I manually added in my image editor the staircases, in green.

On the right is the second floor of the building. The green dotted rectangles are the staircases from the level below, and in yellow are the rooms I manually created in my image editor "around" those staircases.

[image]

Comment: A visual example may be helpful.

Comment: just added a screenshot and more explanations

Comment: Could you side-step the issue by placing all the staircases before splitting any of the floors into rooms?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your proposition but the issue is in generating the level the staircases lead to. So in a sense, staircases of level N are already placed before splitting the rooms of the level N+1

Comment: Yes, there are design rules and heuristics, depending on your paradigm and application.  What you've presented seems to have characteristics in common with both microprocessor design (with vias) and with home design (staircases).  However, your presentation doesn't match either.  Most of all, you've left your various rules and preferences far too loose for me to contribute suggestions: without clearly defined requirements and outcomes, designing an algorithm is not yet possible.

Comment: What are you actually (well, virtually, for teh video game) constructing?  What are these "rooms"?  What is a "staircase"?  Your drawings show that a "staircase" shifts position and changes sides between floors, in a fashion that suggests these are not simple stairways -- perhaps ladders?  The rooms don't seem to follow any considerations for a load-bearing frame.

Comment: So ... what are your design *rules*, and what do you specifically *not* care about?  Of the things in between, what preferences do you have?  When do you stop dividing rooms?  What considerations do you have for access and traffic flow?  We can handle all of this by combining appropriate principles of design, but different outcomes suggest different rules, and sometimes different starting points for each floor's design.

Comment: I edited again the question. I hope this will be clearer now

Comment: Isn't it simply a matter of checking if your split crosses a staircase (and if it does, move it until it doesn't)?

Comment: In the end yes. It was simply a matter of moving the split line when it crosses a staircase. I was over-engineering the problem apparently...